# How to include FK tables using Get methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

i have a method that i call from the server i retrieve me the context from a table it's all correct but on the client side i don't want to use the FK ID to show on the view and for that i need to include de FK table to get all them values... Firstable i have "_context.Curso.Include(c => c.GrauAcademico);" but whith this on the client side i'm not using the get method from the server side so i delete that. Now i'm confused and i don't know how to include the FK table.

**GET Server method**

```
        // GET: api/Curso
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Curso> GetCurso()
    {            
        return _context.Curso;
    }
```

**GET Client method**

```
        // GET: Cursos
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<Curso> cursos = new List<Curso>();
        string path = "api/Curso";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpRequestBuilder.WebApiClient.GetAsync(path);

        //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            cursos = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Curso>>();
        }

        return View(cursos);       
    }
```

**Locals Debugger**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1c26.png]

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<ModelsLibrary.Curso>

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
<a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GrauAcademico)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GrauAcademico.TipoGrau)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CursoId">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.CursoId">Details</a> 
  |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CursoId">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Hi want to use values from *GrauAcademico* table that is the FK of *Curso* but without getting the values from the table is impossible to show them...

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Curso> GetCurso()
{            
    return _context.Curso;
}
```

This is very bad form, and will effectively return all rows from that table across the network.  Just imagine what would happen if this were the `Users` table (and, yes, I've worked on a project that did just that.

What you should be doing is creating a ViewModel that only returns the records and the fields your function requires.

For example:

```
public class CursoViewModel
{ 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public string TipoGrau {get;set;}
}

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<CursoViewModel> GetCurso()
{            
    var records = _context.Curso.Include(c=>c.GrauAcademico);

    return records.Select(x=>new CursoViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Nome = x.Nome,
        TipoGrau = x.GrauAcademico.Tipo,
    }
}
```

This means you will also have to have this view model in the client side, but that's OK.

The other thing is that the database access in the service should be abstracted away, but that's a whole nother question.

Comment: Yes.  I presume the server side is the only one with direct access to the database.